# How to upload csv file into mysql database faster

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I want to upload a csv file into mysql database through php. 
I already have more than 20,000 records in database. now when i upload csv file containing around 1000 records in it, it takes very much time to upload on local machine itself.

Please help and suggest optimized query to upload csv file into mysql database having large number of records.

Does number of records affect performance of database..??

**EDIT from comments**

Currently used code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$file_name' IGNORE 
INTO TABLE import 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES (@srno,@customer_name,@date,@mobno,@city,@state,@type,@telecaller) 
SET customer_name=@customer_name,date=@date,mobno=@mobno,city=@city, state=@state,type=@type,telecaller=@telecaller,datetime='$datetime';
```

Comment: Do you have many indexes on that database? How do you insert the new entries (code)?

Comment: 20,000 and 1,000 are not large numbers of records. You are asking for help with performance, but you are not showing us how you are currently loading data into the database - we can't help without knowing that.

Comment: right now i am using LOAD DATA INFILE '$file_name' IGNORE INTO TABLE import
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                IGNORE 1 LINES
                (@srno,@customer_name,@date,@mobno,@city,@state,@type,@telecaller)
                SET customer_name=@customer_name,date=@date,mobno=@mobno,city=@city,
                state=@state,type=@type,telecaller=@telecaller,datetime='$datetime'; This query to upload csv into mysql database. but it takes about an half an hour to upload csv containig more than 2000 records

Comment: i dont have too much indexes. i only have 8 columns and id as primary key and mobno as unique

Comment: How could it possibly take too long to insert a measly 1000 line CSV file? How long is it taking, and why do you need it to be done faster?

Comment: it is taking near about half an hour to an hour. initially it was working smoothly. but later on with increase in data , it started to take plenty of time to upload. An hour to upload csv file is not good, i think. so just want to optimize query, or change the query

Comment: If it's taking 30 minutes to do a bulk insert of 1000 lines from a CSV file, then something else is very, very wrong. You might want to check and see if your hard drive is dying.

Comment: i dont know whats the problem. but i want to ask that, if there is any problem in query in my code. If query is alright then i will check for hardware and other issues.

Comment: Also, add some logging to determine if the bottleneck is actually in the bulk CSV insert or in moving the CSV across the network (which still shouldn't take anywhere near 30 minutes).

Comment: the csv file is on local machine itself. it i upload csv with only 1 record in it, still it is taking half an hour time.

Comment: @RoshanG - Then I'd recommend running some diagnostics on your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

USE command line tool of mysql: LOAD DATA INFILE

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: i am currently using load data infile query. but it takes too much time to upload csv file

Comment: Please check the index of your table.. If possible first remove index.. then import data.. then add index again..

Answer (score 0):

Use [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function to load data from csv file using php, format it the way you want and create the query to submit to mysql db. I have used it to create a db with 1.5M rows using csv files containing more than 10000 records in each file without any problem. 1000 records shouldn't be a problem.

Example:

```
      $h = fopen("your_file.csv", "r");
      $data = fgetcsv($h, "10000", ",");
```

You will have first line in your csv file in $data[0]. $data[0][0] will contain the first word delimited with ",".
For example: if you have:    "cat, dog, rat" then,

```
    $data[0][0] = "cat"
    $data[0][1] = "dog"
```

etc. Now since you have the records in the $data array, you can use it to make sqls and insert them to db

Comment: Can u please put an example. It will help me alot.

Comment: That would not be faster in most cases (when not using MyISAM tables). LOAD DATA INFILE is faster than bulk INSERT, as there is less overhead to parse the data, however the difference is negligible. See this [related answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16822)